# Java, rock paper scissors game, I want the user input to be in letters instead of numbers

Tags: java

I'm currently taking a programming course online and I'm pretty new to Java. For my assignment, I need to create a rock paper scissors game. Currently, I'm asking the user to input 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors. However, I think it would be more user friendly if I asked the user to input r for rock, p for paper, or s fo scissors. If the user doesn't input r, p, or s, the program should end (to prevent errors). What should I change to do so? Please nothing too complicated as I'm new.

EDIT: Thanks for everyone's help! I submitted my revised code and got full marks! Thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Thanks for everyone's help! I submitted my revised code and got full marks! Thanks to everyone!

Here is my code:

```
public class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //user prompted to make choice
        System.out.println("Welcome! Choose 0 for rock, 1 for paper, or 2 for scissors.");
        int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
        if(choice <0 || choice >2){ //if user input is not 0, 1, or 2 = game ends
            System.out.println("Please try again!");
            System.exit(0);
        }


        //comp chooses # above 0.0000000000... but below 3.0000....; (int) cuts off decimal part = integer
        int compchoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);


        //decides if user wins or loses
        //if compchoice is same as userchoice = tie
        if (compchoice == choice){
            if (choice == 0) {
                System.out.println("both chose rock ");
                System.out.println("tie");
            }
            else if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("both chose paper");
                System.out.println("tie");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Both chose scissors");
                System.out.println("tie");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here `int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());` you have defined user's choice to be a type of int.. Simply change it to `String choice = scan.next();` and that's it.

Note, you will have to change the logic in if statements as they are now comparing int values. Best way to compare strings is to use `.equals()` method

As for opponent's random choice, instead `int compchoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);` that is also return type int, you need to generate a random char. There are a number of ways to achieve this but in my opinion this one is the cleanest:

```
List<String> myList = Arrays.asList("s", "p", "r");
Random rnd = new Random();
int randomItem = rnd.nextInt(myList.size());
String randomElement = myList.get(randomItem);
```

Answer (score 1):

The least intrusive way to change this would be to check for `r`/`R`, `p`/`P` or `s`/`S` with a [switch statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) and then set `choice` to an `int` according to it - so that the rest of your code just works and doesn't have to be changed:

```java
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

//user prompted to make choice
System.out.println("Welcome! Choose R for rock, P for paper, or S for scissors.");
String input = scan.nextLine();

int choice = 0;

switch (input) {
    case "r":
    case "R":
        choice = 0;
        break;
    case "p":
    case "P":
        choice = 1;
        break;
    case "s":
    case "S":
        choice = 2;
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Please try again!");
        scan.close();
        System.exit(0);
}

//// ... continue with your code....
// comp chooses # above 0.0000000000... but below 3.0000....; (int) cuts off // decimal part = integer
// int compchoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);
// ... and so on ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line that says:

```
int choice = Integer.parseInt(scan.next());
```

with:

```
String answer = scan.next();
int choice = answer.length() == 1 ? "rps".indexOf(answer.charAt(0)) : -1;
```

The second line above tests that the response contained a single character and if so, returns that character's position within "rps" - thus, 0 for 'r', 1 for 'p', and 2 for 's' as before. If it's not one of those characters, `indexOf` returns -1 (which you'll then reject).

You may want to also experiment with:

```
private static String[] CHOICES = { "rock", "paper", "scissors" };
```

Which would let you do things like:

```
System.out.println("You chose " + CHOICES[choice]);
System.out.println("I chose " + CHOICES[compchoice]);
```

Then you can output a final line about the result - which then becomes much simpler than a tree of if/elses for every possible case.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int[] randomNumbers = new int[] { 16, 18, 19 };
int nextRandomNumberIndex = rnd.nextInt(randomNumbers.length);
char c = (char) (randomNumbers[nextRandomNumberIndex] + 64);
```

c will be either 'R', 'P' or 'S' and replace 64 with 96 if you want 'r', 'p' or 's'

Answer (score 0):

Well, firsly, as @gorane already said, just write `String choice = scan.next();`
Further, you want to have some String constants, so make the constants:

```
private static final String ROCK = "r";
private static final String PAPER = "p";
private static final String SCISSORS = "s";
```

And then, you have unique Strings and corresponding integers, it might be a good solution to create a Map:

```
private static Map<Integer, String> options = new HashMap<>();
options.put(0, ROCK);
options.put(1, PAPER);
options.put(2, SCISSORS);
```

So in the end it would look like this:

```
public class main {

    private static final String ROCK = "r";
    private static final String PAPER = "p";
    private static final String SCISSORS = "s";
    private static Map<Integer, String> options = new HashMap<>();

    // Here I'm using static initializer, this code works when the first instance of this class is created
    static {
        options.put(0, ROCK);
        options.put(1, PAPER);
        options.put(2, SCISSORS);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        //user prompted to make choice
        System.out.println("Welcome! Choose r for rock, p for paper, or s for scissors.");
        String choice = scan.next();
        if(!options.containsValue(choice)){ // if user input is wrong String
            System.out.println("Please try again!");
            System.exit(0);
        }

        //comp chooses # above 0.0000000000... but below 3.0000....; (int) cuts off decimal part = integer
        int compchoice = (int)(Math.random()*3);

        //decides if user wins or loses
        //if compchoice is same as userchoice = tie
        if (options.get(comchoice).equals(choice)){
            // Nice place to use switch-case!
            switch (choice) {
                case ROCK:
                    System.out.println("both chose rock ");
                    System.out.println("tie");
                    break;
                case PAPER:
                    System.out.println("both chose paper");
                    System.out.println("tie");
                    break;
                case SCISSORS:
                    System.out.println("Both chose scissors");                    
                    System.out.println("tie");
                    break;
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }
        ...
```

And I think you got the point